# How to export Firefox user settings only?

Tags: firefox, xml

When I install firefox, I alter some of the default settings, some examples would be *set homepage to blank*, *never remember history*, *change default download location*. I do this in ***Tools > Options > ...***

How can I export just the settings only without backing up the whole Firefox Profile in **%APPDATA%/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/...**

I assume there is some file which stores this information?

I do not want passwords, bookmarks, and all the rest that comes with most backup tools.

Answer (score 0):

User settings should be stored in `%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<Profile Folder>\prefs.js`